# Android compatible devices with Appcelerator 5.5.1

Tags: android, configuration, appcelerator, compatibility

I've just published an update of my app on Play Store.
The news are essentially coming from Appcelerator that I update from SDK3.5.2 to SDK5.5.1.
My manifest.xml files contains this :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
```

(3 sizes of screen : small, large, xlarge)
My previous version was compatible with every devices listed in the Developper Console (I had android:targetSdkVersion="16"), but now I missed quite half of the devices and I can't figure why.

It seems the Android 4.4 devices (and maybe previous versions) are no more compatible.

What should I look at to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely not the version but the features you are using. Easiest way to check is compile your app for either the android emulator or a device then check the build/android folder for the AndroidManifest.xml file. When you look inside you will see what android permissions and features are being asked for by your app.

For example, if you put code to 'place a phone call' in your app, appcelerator would require the android.hardware.telephony feature enabled. So, every tablet on the market would be excluded because they don't have telephony features. You can check out a list of features available in android here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Compare the list in your manifest file and see what might be causing the elimination of devices. For example, I use a module for barcode reading that automatically enables autofocus and flash in my manifest. If I publish, again many tablets are excluded because they don't have flash, so I have to manually edit my AndroidManifest file and change the line from:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>
```

to

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
```

Once you have the fixed manifest file you can manually force Appcelerator to use your manifest by copying it into platform/android folder. Realize that you'll need to do this every time you compile for release to the play store.

Ray

Comment: Thank you Ray, this was exactly my problem and I managed to fix it with your explanations. Thank you again !